# NextJs css modules - variable in className

Tags: next.js, css-modules

I have a loop to duplicate elements several times. And I want to assign dynamic className to each element. I tried this method but the className is showing as `ClassName='undefined1'` `ClassName='undefined2'` , etc

```
import Style from './css/Style.module.css'

function component() {
  return (
  <div>
   {[...Array(7)].map((e, i) => {
       const numIn = i + 1
       return (
           <img className={`${Style.logo}${numIn}`} src='/assets/svg/logo.svg' alt="" key={i} />
       )
   })}
</div>
)
}
```

Desired outcome:

```
<img className='logo1' />
<img className='logo2' />
<img className='logo3' />
<img className='logo4' />
<img className='logo5' />
<img className='logo6' />
```

Style.module.css:

```
.logo1 {
   width: calc(112px * 2);
   margin-top: -2rem;
   margin-left: 38vw;
}

.logo2 {
    width: calc( 5rem * 2);
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-left: 60vw;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.logo3 {
    width: calc( 4rem * 2);
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 80vw;
    transform: rotate(-8deg);    
}

//etc
```

edit: added Style.module.css file

Comment: can you post `Style.module.css` ?

Comment: @Nico added it.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Modules locally scope CSS by automatically creating a unique class name, that means that if your `Style.module.css` is something like this :

```
.logo1{
  // some css rules
}

.logo2{
  // some css rules
}
```

Next will generate for each class name (`logo1`,`logo2` ecc..) a  **unique classname** different from the one provided inside `Style.module.css`
Basically `Styles` is an object with the class names as  keys and the unique class names generated by next.js as property.
This mean that you have to grab the class name in this way  `` className={Style[`logo${numIn}`]} ``:

```
import Style from './css/Style.module.css'

    function component() {
      return (
      <div>
       {[...Array(7)].map((e, i) => {
           const numIn = i + 1
           return (
               <img className={Style[`logo${numIn}`]} src='/assets/svg/logo.svg' alt="" key={i} />
           )
       })}
    </div>
    )
    }
```

Note that the rendered html will have different class names but with the right css rules.

Answer (score -1):

`const numIn` change to `let numIn`

```
//define you variable, any manipulations here 
let variable = "text-center"
```

And you add your variable like this:

```
<img className={variable} />
```

or

```
<img className={`logo${numIn}`} />
```

Your problem is `Style.logo` is `undefined`, maybe it's `style.logo` or `styles.logo`?

Comment: hi i edited the code to better illustrate the problem. i tried your code but it doesnt work. as css modules reqiures this type of syntax:  `ClassName={Style.logo}`